# Advices/tips on optimizing an Oracle SQL query executing on significant volumes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization, sql-optimization

Don't run just after seeing the Oracle SQL query below ! :)

I put the complete query in ordrer to ask for some advices on optimizations.
I used the Oracle explain plan tool to help me identify some ways of optimizations but I'm quite stuck with it. 
Could you give me some advices/tips/good practices/ on potential optimizations of this query ?

Facts :

- Tables PERSONNE and AFFAIRE contains about 1 million rows
- Table EVENEMENT contains about 30 millions rows

Thanks in advance !

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM(
    (SELECT DISTINCT PER_ID 
        FROM (
            SELECT evt.PER_ID, MAX(evt.EVT_DATE_UPDATE) DMAX 
            FROM EVENEMENT evt, PERSONNE per
            WHERE per.PER_ID = evt.PER_ID 
                    AND (per.PER_SI_DECES <> 1) 
            GROUP BY evt.PER_ID) dos
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM AFFAIRE aff, PRISE_EN_CHARGE pec
                    WHERE dos.PER_ID = aff.PER_ID 
                            AND aff.AFF_ID = pec.AFF_ID 
                            AND pec.PEC_ETAT = 'A')
            AND DMAX < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-60)
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT per.PER_ID 
        FROM PERSONNE per 
        WHERE per.PER_SI_DECES = 1
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT 1 
                        FROM AFFAIRE aff, PRISE_EN_CHARGE pec
                        WHERE per.PER_ID = aff.PER_ID 
                                AND aff.AFF_ID = pec.AFF_ID 
                                AND pec.PEC_ETAT = 'A') 
                                AND EXISTS (
                                        SELECT 1 
                                        FROM AFFAIRE aff 
                                        WHERE per.PER_ID = aff.PER_ID)
    )
)
WHERE PER_ID NOT IN (
                    (SELECT pdo.PER_ID
                        FROM PERSONNE_DOSSIER pdo, EVENEMENT evt 
                        WHERE pdo.ROP_ID = 1
                            AND evt.PDO_ID = pdo.PDO_ID 
                            AND evt.PER_ID <> pdo.PER_ID
                    )
                    UNION
                    (SELECT pdo.PER_ID
                        FROM PERSONNE_DOSSIER pdo, DESTINATAIRE_EVENEMENT des, EVENEMENT evt 
                        WHERE pdo.ROP_ID = 1
                            AND des.PDO_ID = pdo.PDO_ID 
                            AND des.EVT_ID = evt.EVT_ID
                            AND evt.PER_ID <> pdo.PER_ID)
                    UNION
                    (SELECT dgi.PER_ID
                        FROM DEMANDE_GIDE dgi, AFFAIRE aff 
                        where aff.AFF_ID = dgi.AFF_ID 
                                and aff.PER_ID <> dgi.PER_ID)
);
```

Here is the corresponding explain plan :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                        |     1 |    13 |       |   194K  (1)|
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                    |                        |     1 |    13 |       |            |
|*  2 |   FILTER                           |                        |       |       |       |            |
|   3 |    VIEW                            |                        |  1309 | 17017 |       |   192K  (1)|
|   4 |     SORT UNIQUE                    |                        |  1309 | 35344 |       |   192K (24)|
|   5 |      UNION-ALL                     |                        |       |       |       |            |
|*  6 |       FILTER                       |                        |       |       |       |            |
|   7 |        HASH GROUP BY               |                        |     1 |    28 |       |   149K  (1)|
|*  8 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI       |                        |  1021K|    27M|    12M|   149K  (1)|
|   9 |          VIEW                      | VW_SQ_1                |   756K|  4433K|       | 26286   (1)|
|* 10 |           HASH JOIN                |                        |   756K|    14M|    14M| 26286   (1)|
|* 11 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN    | IDX_PEC_AFF_SER_ETAT   |   756K|  5910K|       |  4080   (3)|
|  12 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL       | AFFAIRE                |  3146K|    36M|       | 17884   (1)|
|* 13 |          HASH JOIN                 |                        |  3648K|    76M|  2560K|   115K  (1)|
|* 14 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | PERSONNE               |   130K|  1021K|       | 14179   (2)|
|  15 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | EVENEMENT              |    29M|   391M|       | 65035   (2)|
|* 16 |       HASH JOIN SEMI               |                        |  1308 | 35316 |       | 43080   (1)|
|* 17 |        HASH JOIN ANTI              |                        |  1308 | 27468 |  2560K| 41493   (1)|
|* 18 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL          | PERSONNE               |   130K|  1021K|       | 14179   (2)|
|  19 |         VIEW                       | VW_SQ_2                |   756K|  9605K|       | 26286   (1)|
|* 20 |          HASH JOIN                 |                        |   756K|    14M|    14M| 26286   (1)|
|* 21 |           INDEX FAST FULL SCAN     | IDX_PEC_AFF_SER_ETAT   |   756K|  5910K|       |  4080   (3)|
|  22 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | AFFAIRE                |  3146K|    36M|       | 17884   (1)|
|  23 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | FK_PER_AFF             |  3146K|    18M|       |  1572   (2)|
|  24 |    SORT UNIQUE                     |                        |     6 |   171 |       |  1757 (100)|
|  25 |     UNION-ALL                      |                        |       |       |       |            |
|  26 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |                        |       |       |       |            |
|  27 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |                        |     2 |    46 |       |     8   (0)|
|* 28 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PERSONNE_DOSSIER       |     1 |    15 |       |     4   (0)|
|* 29 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN           | FK_PER_PDO             |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)|
|* 30 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN            | FK_EVT_PDO             |     2 |       |       |     2   (0)|
|* 31 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | EVENEMENT              |     2 |    16 |       |     4   (0)|
|  32 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |                        |       |       |       |            |
|  33 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |                        |     3 |   108 |       |    16   (0)|
|  34 |        NESTED LOOPS                |                        |     3 |    72 |       |    10   (0)|
|* 35 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PERSONNE_DOSSIER       |     1 |    15 |       |     4   (0)|
|* 36 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FK_PER_PDO             |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)|
|  37 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DESTINATAIRE_EVENEMENT |     3 |    27 |       |     6   (0)|
|* 38 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FK_DVT_PDO             |     3 |       |       |     2   (0)|
|* 39 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_EVENEMENT           |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|
|* 40 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | EVENEMENT              |     1 |    12 |       |     2   (0)|
|  41 |      NESTED LOOPS                  |                        |       |       |       |            |
|  42 |       NESTED LOOPS                 |                        |     1 |    17 |       |  1730   (2)|
|* 43 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL           | DEMANDE_GIDE           |     1 |     5 |       |  1728   (2)|
|* 44 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_AFFAIRE             |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)|
|* 45 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | AFFAIRE                |     1 |    12 |       |     2   (0)|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter( NOT EXISTS ( (SELECT "PDO"."PER_ID" FROM "EVENEMENT" "EVT","PERSONNE_DOSSIER" 
              "PDO" WHERE "PDO"."PER_ID"=:B1 AND "PDO"."ROP_ID"=1 AND "EVT"."PDO_ID"="PDO"."PDO_ID" AND 
              "EVT"."PER_ID"<>:B2 AND "EVT"."PER_ID"<>"PDO"."PER_ID" AND "EVT"."PDO_ID" IS NOT NULL)UNION 
              (SELECT "PDO"."PER_ID" FROM "EVENEMENT" "EVT","DESTINATAIRE_EVENEMENT" "DES","PERSONNE_DOSSIER" 
              "PDO" WHERE "PDO"."PER_ID"=:B3 AND "PDO"."ROP_ID"=1 AND "DES"."PDO_ID"="PDO"."PDO_ID" AND 
              "DES"."PDO_ID" IS NOT NULL AND "DES"."EVT_ID"="EVT"."EVT_ID" AND "EVT"."PER_ID"<>:B4 AND 
              "EVT"."PER_ID"<>"PDO"."PER_ID")UNION (SELECT "DGI"."PER_ID" FROM "AFFAIRE" "AFF","DEMANDE_GIDE" 
              "DGI" WHERE "DGI"."AFF_ID" IS NOT NULL AND "DGI"."PER_ID"=:B5 AND "AFF"."AFF_ID"="DGI"."AFF_ID" 
              AND "AFF"."PER_ID"<>:B6 AND "AFF"."PER_ID"<>"DGI"."PER_ID")))
   6 - filter(MAX("EVT"."EVT_DATE_UPDATE")<ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE@!,-60))
   8 - access("EVT"."PER_ID"="ITEM_1")
  10 - access("AFF"."AFF_ID"="PEC"."AFF_ID")
  11 - filter("PEC"."PEC_ETAT"='A')
  13 - access("PER"."PER_ID"="EVT"."PER_ID")
  14 - filter("PER"."PER_SI_DECES"<>1)
  16 - access("PER"."PER_ID"="AFF"."PER_ID")
  17 - access("PER"."PER_ID"="ITEM_2")
  18 - filter("PER"."PER_SI_DECES"=1)
  20 - access("AFF"."AFF_ID"="PEC"."AFF_ID")
  21 - filter("PEC"."PEC_ETAT"='A')
  28 - filter("PDO"."ROP_ID"=1)
  29 - access("PDO"."PER_ID"=:B1)
  30 - access("EVT"."PDO_ID"="PDO"."PDO_ID")
       filter("EVT"."PDO_ID" IS NOT NULL)
  31 - filter("EVT"."PER_ID"<>:B1 AND "EVT"."PER_ID"<>"PDO"."PER_ID")
  35 - filter("PDO"."ROP_ID"=1)
  36 - access("PDO"."PER_ID"=:B1)
  38 - access("DES"."PDO_ID"="PDO"."PDO_ID")
       filter("DES"."PDO_ID" IS NOT NULL)
  39 - access("DES"."EVT_ID"="EVT"."EVT_ID")
  40 - filter("EVT"."PER_ID"<>:B1 AND "EVT"."PER_ID"<>"PDO"."PER_ID")
  43 - filter("DGI"."AFF_ID" IS NOT NULL AND "DGI"."PER_ID"=:B1)
  44 - access("AFF"."AFF_ID"="DGI"."AFF_ID")
  45 - filter("AFF"."PER_ID"<>:B1 AND "AFF"."PER_ID"<>"DGI"."PER_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that can be said and asked here. Use UNION ALL instead of UNION when conditions are mutually exclusive like IS_DECES = 0 vs =1. NOT IN make sure you are not using NULLable column. Try to check to separate parts in UNION inside NOT IN to give better chance for index access. Parallel query should help you here...